# cats effect evaluates only the final for coprehension and ignores rest

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats, category-theory, cats-effect

I'm a newbie to functional programming and cats effect.
Started practicing cats effect 3 with the below code

```
package com.scalaFPLove.FabioLabellaTalks

import cats.effect.IOApp
import cats.effect.{IO, Concurrent}
import cats.effect.kernel.Deferred
import cats.implicits._
import cats.kernel
import cats.effect.kernel.Ref
import cats.effect.unsafe.IORuntime.global

object RefAndDeferredConcurrency extends IOApp.Simple {

  override def run: IO[Unit] = {
    for {
      _ <- IO.println("Hello1")
      _ <- IO.println("World1")
    } yield ()
    for {
      _ <- IO.println("Hello2")
      _ <- IO.println("World2")
    } yield ()
  }
}
```

The output I expected is

Hello1
world1
Hello2
world2

but the actual output is

> Hello2
> world2

Unable to understand the idea behind this, I tried many different things and only the last for comprehension is evaluated ignoring the rest. please help me understand this.

Comment: Others have answered why/how, but you might also want to have the compiler warn you about this code, so that it doesn't happen by accident. Add the `-Wvalue-discard` and `-Wnonunit-statement` flags to your `scalacOptions`. In this example, the nonunit-statement lint would detect the bug in the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest explanation is this: `IO[A]` is like `() => A` (or `() => Future[A]`). Except it comes with `map` and `flatMap` used in for-comprehension.

When you have:

```
override def run: IO[Unit] = {
  for {
    _ <- IO.println("Hello1")
    _ <- IO.println("World1")
  } yield ()
  for {
    _ <- IO.println("Hello2")
    _ <- IO.println("World2")
  } yield ()
}
```

it's basically very similar to:

```
def IOprintln(str: String): () => Unit = _ => println(str)

def run: () => Unit = {
  () => {
    val _ = IOprintln("Hello1")()
    val _ = IOprintln("World1")()
    ()
  }
  () => {
    val _ = IOprintln("Hello2")()
    val _ = IOprintln("World2")()
    ()
  }
}
```

(In your program `run` is called in `IOApp.Simple`'s `main`).

You see what happened here? We created 2 *recipes* for a program, but never combined them together, and the value of block of code is the last expression.

And these expressions with *recepies* - by the very nature of `() => ...` - are **not** computing side effects until you run them. It' very useful because it allow you to do things like:

```
def program(condition: Boolean) = {
  val a = IO.println("hello world 1")
  val b = IO.println("hello world 2")
  if (condition) a else b
}
```

where our program would print only 1 thing, depending on the condition, but not 2 of them at once before even checking which is needed.

Basically what would be executed (somewhere, at some point) is the last IO expression. If you build it using `flatMap` then only the last expression in that `flatMap` would become part of the recipe, and so on. E.g. your original program can be desugared to:

```
override def run: IO[Unit] = {
  IO.println("Hello1").flatMap { _ =>
    IO.println("World1").map { _ =>
      ()
    }
  }
  IO.println("Hello2").flatMap { _ =>
    IO.println("World2").map { _ =>
      ()
    }
  }
}
```

and when you remember that

- `IO` is a value that someone somewhere evaluates (like a function)
- when evaluating data you can only evaluate what's become a part of that data
- the value of a block is the value of it's last expression

it should be clear what will and what will not become part of a final program.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailing. used to imperative programming, its hard to digest this, but cats effect evaluates even the main program lazily :). so thumb rule is join them with *> or >> [ if recursive]!

Comment: Yes, if you have a few `IO` values and you want all of them to happen, then you should use something like: `a >> b`, `a << b`, `(a, b).tupled`, `(a, b).parTupled` (same like previous one but computing both branches in parallel), `a.map2(b) { (a1, b1) => ... }` (work only for 2), `(a, b).mapN { (a2, b1) => ... }` (works for 2 and more ios), `... .parMapN ...`, `a.flatMap { a1 => b }` or for-comprehension, `List(a, b).sequence` or `.parSequence` (also look into `.traverse` and `.parTraverse`)  and so on.